# Check input modified in html without using form Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

How to check if input is modified in html code, without using any form

I have below code

```
 <textarea #txt (change)="data.url = txt.value" placeholder="https://"
 [value]="data.url" ></textarea>
  <span *ngIf="!txt.value">
   <span class="">Required</span>
 </span>
  <span *ngIf="txt && txt.dirty && !customValidationService.urlValidator(txt.value)">
    <span class="">Invalid</span>
 </span>
```

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: you may need to use a  `callback` on the `change` event

Comment: isn't this possible in html only, using callback is simple